# T-SQL Query Counting Same Column Multipe Times

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-ce

I am new to SQL and I am trying to build a SQL query against a SQL Server CE 4 database that counts the same column (`CompanyName`) multiple times based off its `Active` status (0 or 1). I need the Total, Active and In Active by State. I think this is a subquery that for Total, Active and In Active, but am not sure how to build it.

Essentially I want to have a table that will provide a result like this based off the `CompanyName`.

```
State     Total Active InActive
Texas      10     6       4 
Florida    15     5       10
```

The basic query I have so far is

```
SELECT State, COUNT(CompanyName) AS Total
FROM  JobApps AS j
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUM` over the same grouping, using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT State, COUNT(CompanyName) AS Total
, SUM(CASE Active WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Active
, SUM(CASE Active WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS InActive
FROM  JobApps AS j
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY Total DESC
```